# Custom typ serialization with Protobuf-net

Tags: c#, serialization, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

Is it possible to use protobuf-net with custom type serialization?

Here is a pseudo example of what I have

```
  //some user defined type
  public class SomeMessage 
  {
       public ActorRef ActorRef {get;set;}
  }

  //classes in my framework
  public abstract ActorRef
  {
       public string Path {get;set;}
  }

  public class FooActorRef : ActorRef
  {
  }

  public class BarActorRef : ActorRef
  {
  }
```

I need to serialize all of the "ActorRef" types as the same type, I just need to store the "Path" and ignore the rest.
I also need to be able to intercept/resolve the deserialization of the "ActorRef" here.
So when the deserializer finds a serialized "path" I need it to call my custom handler and resolve the ActorRef this way.

So pretty much, custom serialization and deserialization of the ActorRef and it's subtypes.
e.g.

```
  //I want something like this to be called upon deserialization..
  public ActorRef DeserializeActorRef(SerializerSpecificData x)
  { 
          var path = x.Path;
          return myContext.ResolveActorRef(path);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using "Surrogates", this does exactly what I need here.